# How to download knime partitioning test and train file

Tags: dataset, partitioning, knime

i have a workflow with knime. and I want to partition the data test and train but i couldn't download.
I need that files another platform.

Comment: Not sure what the problem is? You can't download KNIME, can't download workflow or you can't import data into KNIME. Or something else?

Comment: Please try and explain more clearly. Do you already have a KNIME workflow that does the partitioning, and you want to save the two data partitions? If so please post an image of the workflow showing which node is which. If you haven't started this yet, have you looked at the example workflows in KNIME?